# There is no reference to AppLocalesMetadataHolderService in Per-app language preferences Manifet

Tags: android, locale, android-appcompat

According to the official documentation of Android, in order to implement the ability to change the language using [Per-app language preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#android12-impl) feature and support Android versions lower than 12, I must use the following piece of code in the manifest:

```
<application
  ...
  <service
    android:name="androidx.appcompat.app.AppLocalesMetadataHolderService"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:exported="false">
    <meta-data
      android:name="autoStoreLocales"
      android:value="true" />
  </service>
  ...
</application>
```

But after adding this piece of code, the reference to `androidx.appcompat.app.AppLocalesMetadataHolderService` is not recognized by Android Studio and gives an error, how can I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `appcompat` library used in this service must be a version higher than 1.6.x so that the reference class given for the service is present in the version.

In this case, the used library was 1.5.0, which was fixed after updating to version 1.6.0-beta01:

```
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0")
```

**Upgrade to:**

```
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-beta01")
```